# SAP Hybris Assisted Service Module (ASM) - can't generate component

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, add-on

I've installed and tested ASM on my localhost successfully (we use Hybris 1811). Then I wanted to transfer it on our dev server (actually it was only changes in `localextensions.xml` and regenerated `extensionsinfo.xml`), so in `extensionsinfo.xml` of my storefront there is the addon registrated like this:

```
<requires-extension name="assistedservicestorefront "/>
```

But it doesn't generate files in views:

```
[DefaultCMSComponentRendererRegistry] Error processing component tag. currentComponent [AssistedServiceComponentModel (8796814312508@2)] exception: 
File [&#47;WEB-INF&#47;views&#47;responsive&#47;cms&#47;assistedservicecomponent.jsp] not found
```

I've imported the same `.impex` file as in the manual for installing ASM (from `help.hybris.com`) and as on the localhost (`cms-content.impex` to include component and Jsp).

Even though I run update in HAC, I tried to sync content catalog. I checked extensions in HAC, it contains same ASM extensions as on my local machine: `assistedservicefacades`, `assistedserviceservices`, `assistedservicestorefront`.
When I checked the backoffice, the component with that ID is really there and it's in online catalog.

How do I make those files to generate? Or should I somehow override them with my custom views? But I think it would be bad approach.

UPDATE: I also tried to add this entry to `project.properties` of my storefront:

```
sikob2cstorefront.additionalWebSpringConfigs.assistedservicestorefront=classpath\:/assistedservicestorefront/web/spring/assistedservicestorefront-web-spring.xml
```

but then I got the error loading beans:

```
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultStorefrontTenantDefaultFilterChainList': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AssistedservicestorefrontFilterListMergeDirective' defined in class path resource [assistedservicestorefront/web/spring/assistedservicestorefront-web-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'assistedServiceFilter' while setting add; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'assistedServiceFilter' defined in class path resource [assistedservicestorefront/web/spring/assistedservicestorefront-web-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'assistedServicePathRestrictionEvaluator' while setting bean property 'assistedServicePathRestrictionEvaluator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'assistedServicePathRestrictionEvaluator' available
```

Comment: Have you installed `assistedservicestorefront` as an addon?

Comment: Yes, on my local machine I installed it as an addon `ant addoninstall -Daddonnames="assistedservicestorefront" -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront="mystorefront"`, so it updated `extensionsinfo.xml` and I can see the extension in hac.

Comment: so you need to run the same command in other environments as well. Let me add the answer in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Install assistedservicestorefront
# Replace Mystorefront with your storefront extension name
ant addoninstall -Daddonnames="assistedservicestorefront" -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront="Mystorefront"
```

I think you have missed installing the assistedservicestorefront addon or if you've already installed then check whether below changes have taken place on your server.

### addoninstall command makes below changes

- Adds assistedservicestorefront into extensioninfo.xml of your storefront extension

  like
  `<requires-extension name="assistedservicestorefront "/>`
- Generate a new **project.properties** file from **project.properties.template** inside assistedservicestorefront, which has following entries.

Replace **yacceleratorstorefront** with your storefront extension name in the below property.

```
#Specifies the location of the spring context file added automatically to the global platform application context.
assistedservicestorefront.application-context=assistedservicestorefront-spring.xml

yacceleratorstorefront.additionalWebSpringConfigs.assistedservicestorefront=classpath:/assistedservicestorefront/web/spring/assistedservicestorefront-web-spring.xml


assistedservicestorefront.javascript.paths.mobile=/responsive/common/js/assistedservicestorefront.js;/responsive/common/js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js;/responsive/common/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js;/responsive/common/js/Chart.min.js;/responsive/common/js/asm.storefinder.js
assistedservicestorefront.javascript.paths.responsive=/responsive/common/js/assistedservicestorefront.js;/responsive/common/js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js;/responsive/common/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js;/responsive/common/js/Chart.min.js;/responsive/common/js/asm.storefinder.js

assistedservicestorefront.css.paths.mobile=/responsive/common/css/assistedservicestorefront.css;/responsive/common/css/storeFinder.css;/responsive/common/css/customer360.css
assistedservicestorefront.css.paths.responsive=/responsive/common/css/assistedservicestorefront.css;/responsive/common/css/storeFinder.css;/responsive/common/css/customer360.css

assistedservicestorefront.redirect.customer_and_cart=/cart
assistedservicestorefront.redirect.customer_only=/my-account
assistedservicestorefront.redirect.error=/
assistedservicestorefront.redirect.order=/my-account/order/%s

assistedservicestorefront.deeplink.link=/assisted-service/emulate

cscokpit.assistedservice.deeplink=true
assistedservicestorefront.profile.cookie.name=profile.tracking.pause

#AIF AJAX call timeout in milliseconds
assistedservicestorefront.aif.timeout=7000
```

So if you don't want to run addoninstall command in each environment then you can manually do these two changes. You can refer to the generated project.properties file inside your addon and copy all those properties to your storefront's project.properties or local.properteis file and commit the changes.

Comment: Please see updated question. I did both things (add extension as required and that property), but then the context initialization failed, see the stack trace. Maybe there's some other property to add?

Comment: Refer to assistedservicestorefront's `project.properties` in your local system and try adding all those in local.properties. Not only additionalWebSpringConfigs.

Comment: I think you are missing `assistedservicestorefront.application-context=assistedservicestorefront-spring.xml`

Comment: I would suggest running the addonInstall command on your server as you did in your local and all set. In that case, you don't require to set these properties manually. Yes but you need to take care of running addoninstall for each new hybris environment setup.

Comment: Adding all the `project.properties` from ASM extension to my storefront extension did the final thing, thank you.

Comment: I'm glad that this helped you!!